# How can I decompose an object and add it to a list succintly?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

If I have a class e.g.

```
data class Departments (
  val customerFacing: Commercial,  
  val warehouse: Operational,
  val accounting: Auditing)
```

Is there a more Kotlin like way to achieve the following?

```
val list: MutableList<Sections<*>> = arrayListOf()
if(deparments.customerFacing != null) {  
   list.add(Section(manager, deparments.customerFacing)
}
if(deparments.warehouse != null) {  
   list.add(Section(manager, deparments.warehouse)
}
if(deparments.accounting != null) {  
   list.add(Section(manager, deparments.accounting)
}


data class Section<T>(val manager: String, val section: T)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to represent with Departments class?

Comment: @DiegoMarin: It is just a data class that I want to decompose and put each member in a list (as the class is just a holder of the individual items)

Comment: Does your Section class need a generic type? You said you want to "achieve the following", but there are no raw types allowed in Kotlin in the first place.

Comment: @Tenfour04: Yes I need a generic type. I didn't understand what you mean `there are no raw types allowed in Kotlin in the first place`

Comment: Your example code won't compile because you haven't specified the type for the Section of the list type (leaving it raw). I guess it could be a wild card like `val list =  arrayListOf<Section<*>>()` But then you've lost the type. If you call `list[0].section`, the type will be `Any?`

Comment: @Tenfour04: ah sorry about that. Copy/paste issue for the `<<*>>` but I am not sure I get the problem you describe. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You are storing your Sections in a `List<Section<*>>`. This effectively makes the type of every `section.section` an `Any?` after you retrieve it from the list, so you might as well not have a generic type.

Comment: @Tenfour04: I see. I am using the `manager` as a way to know what type is `T` later. I don't know how else to do it, given that the list has different types of `Ts` added

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Departments class definition its properties can not be null, so you do not need to check for null. But if they were:

```
data class Departments (
  val customerFacing: Commercial?,  
  val warehouse: Operational?,
  val accounting: Auditing?)
```

You do not have to use `if`, you can use the operator `?.` to do safe calls.

```
deparments.customerFacing?.let{list.add(Section(manager, it)}
deparments.warehouse?.let{list.add(Section(manager, it)}
deparments.accounting?.let{list.add(Section(manager, it)}
```

[Execute if not null](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null)

Answer (score 1):

As @alfcope mentioned, if departments fields can be null, they should me modeled as nullable types.

You can do the following:

```
val result = listOf(departments)
    .flatMap { listOfNotNull(it.customerFacing, it.warehouse, it.accounting) }
    .map { Session(manager, it) }
```

Comment: `departments` in not a list. Can I use `flatMap`?

Comment: You can make it a list with `listOf(departments)`

Comment: or just remove the `flatMap` call.

Comment: Sorry, it should be only one .map. Fixed.

Comment: @DiegoMarin: how could I make the `manager` change based on the decomposed item? I don't want to map to the same manager for both it.customerFacing and it.warehouse

Comment: @Tenfour04 is there a way to call a map function directly in an object?

Comment: @Jim you can add manager info inside customerFacing and warehouse objects

Comment: @DiegoMarin: Actually I can't. I need to associate them without it being part of the object.

Comment: You wouldn't need to. `listOfNotNull` is already creating a list for you.

Comment: in this case I think @alfcope solution is more suitable for your case